# alltt package's \alltt{} makes a newline

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

`alltt` causes a line break (newline). How do i suppress this? I want something to the effect of `\verb+HELLO+` in that it does what `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}` does except doesn't cause the line to break.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{alltt}

 \begin{document}

 The line will break HERE: \alltt{a}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: `alltt` should be used as an environment. You probably want `\texttt{a}`.

Comment: Can you make a *real* example of usage?

Comment: `\texttt` makes odd things to hyphens: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9813/81156

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `alltt` defines an environemnt `alltt` that uses a list environment internally. Therefore it cannot be used the same way as `\verb` or `\texttt`.

The main point of package `alltt` is the unchanged use of `\`, `{` and `}`. The following macro `\textalltt` sets verbatim catcodes for its argument except for the three characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textalltt}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\textalltt}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \catcode`\\=\z@
    \catcode`\{=\@ne
    \catcode`\}=\tw@
    \verbatim@font\@noligs
    \@vobeyspaces
    \frenchspacing
    \@textalltt
}
\newcommand*{\@textalltt}[1]{%
    #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Verbatim text: \textalltt{Hello \textbf{\textsl{world}}}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]