# "| shortcut no longer available in babel?

Tags: babel, ligatures, shorthands

In the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106487/difference-between-and-for-breaking-ligatures), people recommend using the "`babel` shorthand" command `"|` to break the ligature in the word `shelfful`. Am I doing this wrong or is this command no longer available in `babel`? (I cannot find a mention of it in the documentation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\begin{document}
shelf"|ful {shelf}ful shelf{}ful shelf\/ful
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add the german shorthands, which knows several `"`-shorthands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}% american still active at \begin{document}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasamerican{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
shelfful shelf"|ful {shelf}ful shelf{}ful shelf\/ful
\end{document}
```

[image]

The german shorthands from file `ngermanb.ldf`:

```
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"`}{\glqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"'}{\grqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"<}{\flqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{">}{\frqq}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"-}{\nobreak\-\bbl@allowhyphens}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"|}{%
  \textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}%
              \allowhyphens}{}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"~}{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"=}{\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip}
```