# babel: Use extra definitions (hyphenation shorthands) in other languages

Tags: babel

- I am writing an English document.
- Normally I write in German.
- The [`babel`package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) offers for German specific commands/shorthands like `"=` for a `-` that does not suppress other hyphenations in the word.
- **I would like to be able to use the `ngerman` shorthands in English.**
- I found `\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}` in the current `babel` manual but it did show now effect.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Testtext. Test"=Text. \foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Test"=Text}
\end{document}

% Related (the first link is in German)
% http://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/Georg.Verweyen/silbentrennung.html
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256740
```

[image]

[image]
*(Taken from an old version of the babel manual (2005). In the current manual, I did not find this table.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading ["| shortcut no longer available in babel?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256740) from 2015 more carefully, I could copy and paste a solution. But I am still interested, if that's the intended way to solve this (2015 vs. 2020)?!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
% See "Languages with only " as defined shorthand character" in babel manual.
% ngerman is one of the languages that uses '"' as the only shorthand character.
\useshorthands{"} 
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
Testtext. Test"=Text. \foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Test"=Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> The command `\languageshorthands` can be used to switch the shorthands
>   on the language level. It takes one argument, the name of a language
>   or none (the latter does what its name suggests). Note that for this
>   to work the language should have been specified as an option when
>   loading the babel package. For example, you can use in `english` the
>   shorthands defined by `ngerman` with [...] (You may also need to activate them as user shorthands in the preamble with, for example,
>   `\useshorthands{...}` or `\useshorthands{...}*`.)

Comment: **Remark:** I can include this in the question, if this is preferred.

Comment: Looks like the correct answer to me.

Comment: @clemens Thanks for the feedback!