# polyglossia: babel hyphenation shorthands for English?

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia, shorthands

I usually write in German, and I'm used to using various `babel` shorthands, e.g. `"=` for an explicit hyphen that does not keep a word from being hyphenated elsewhere. I've found that while these work for German, they do not do so for English.

Others have had the same problem; I've found [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522970/babel-use-extra-definitions-hyphenation-shorthands-in-other-languages), but I'm actually using `polyglossia` rather than `babel` (though with `babelshorthands=true`), and as might be expected the solution provided isn't working.

I'm actually not too hung up on most of the shorthands, but `"=` is extremely useful if you're talking about e. g. `the Lotka"=Volterra predator"=prey model` or some such thing — more so when the individual component words are longer, say when a person is described as `antidisestablishmentarianism"=averse`.

So my question is:

1. Is there a way of enabling `babel`shorthands for English, in `polyglossia`?
2. If there isn't, what's the best way of duplicating the effect of `"=`, with the least effort required? (No listing all possible hyphenation points for each word with an explicit hyphen, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question and [digging into Polyglossia's code](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/gloss-german.ldf#L179), the following appears to work:

```
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\makeatletter\german@shorthands\makeatother
```

There may be unintended side effects, but if so I've not observed them yet.