# Changing font in title

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I am currently using the following code below. I am curious - how can I change the font in the title under SetPaperName? Currently the S does not appear like an S. Is there a similar font I can use to have a better S and how do I change it?

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)
\SetPaperName{The Post}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{The  Post}

%% and also...

\SetPaperSlogan{``testing''}
\SetPaperPrice{\MakeLowercase{https://intothecryptoverse.com/}}

% [LianTze] times (the package not the font) is rather outdated now; use newtx (see later)
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{picinpar}
%uasage of picinpar:
%\begin{window}[1,l,\includegraphics{},caption]xxxxx\end{window}

%% [LianTze] Contains some modifications
\usepackage{newspaper-mod}
%%... so now you can redefine the headline and byline style if you want to.
%% These can be issued just before any
%% byline or headline in the paper, to
%% individually style each article
%%
% \renewcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\Large\lsstyle}
% \renewcommand{\bylinestyle}{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}


%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}

\byline{Introduction }{Benjamin J. Cowen}


\end{multicols}

\closearticle
\end{document}
```

and `newspaper-mod.sty` by LianTze Lim tex.SE user is available:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\huge}
\newcommand{\bylinestyle}{\scshape\Large}
\patchcmd{\headline}{#1}{\headlinestyle #1}{}{}
\patchcmd{\byline}{#1}{\bylinestyle #1}{}{}
```

Comment: Where does `\usepackage{newspaper-mod}` comes from? I think there is a missunderstanding: the `s` is there, but because the used font is a fractur font it is correct written simular to an f (in fractur there is a long and a short s, which is written depends on the position of the s in the word ...)

Comment: right, I just want to use a font that has a better s. I just took this template from overleaf or something. Any way how can I change the font here? I would prefer the s not to look the way it does. It is hard to read

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are seeing using a [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) as well as st- and he-ligatures is correct according to the traditional typographic rules for [blackletter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) fonts. However, there is clear precedence that these rules are not strictly followed for newspaper titles in UK and USA, and this is not a new phenomena:

- First issue of [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/pbox.php?url=http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/retropolis/wp-content/uploads/sites/62/2017/12/Post6Dec1877_edited-1.jpg&w=1484&op=resize&opt=1&filter=antialias&t=20170517) from 1877: No long s, no ligatures
- Early issue of [The Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Times_1788.12.04.jpg) from 1788: No he-ligature, though the long s for Roman type was abandoned only in 1803

In Germany, the situation is different even today:

- [Frankfurter Allgemeine](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/): a k that might be difficult for some people to identify
- [Fränkischer Anzeiger](http://www.fraenkischer-anzeiger.de/): long s as well as k, A and z that might be difficult for some people to identify

(Note that the "difficult to identify shapes" are a result of the used type, which belongs to the Fraktur group. I would be surprised if an anglo-saxon newspaper would use such a font as title face.)

So typographic rules change over time and depend on the cultural context, and in your case it might be appropriate to abandon the traditional rules by breaking up these ligatures ([in a suboptimal way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106487/difference-between-and-for-breaking-ligatures)) via

```
\SetPaperName{Th\/e Pos:\/t}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: I feared someone will come up with that wrong writing! I do not recommend it, because it breaks the writing rules for fractur fonts ...

Comment: Why is this bad? It does exactly what I want!

Comment: @ben See the updated question for more background.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the issue here is that the command `\maketitle` uses the fractur font directly (not very good programming btw ...):

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\begin{center}\small \@paperslogan\end{center}}}}}\hfill%
{\textgoth{\huge\usefont{LYG}{bigygoth}{m}{n} \@papername}}\hfill%  <==================
\raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@paperlocation}}\\
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
}
```

In the preamble of your code you can change this (see `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` needed because the usage of `@` in that code!):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\begin{center}\small \@paperslogan\end{center}}}}}\hfill%
{\Huge\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n} \@papername}\hfill%    % <==================
\raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@paperlocation}}\\
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
}
\makeatother
```

so with the complete mwe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)
\SetPaperName{The Post}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{The  Post}

%% and also...

\SetPaperSlogan{``testing''}
\SetPaperPrice{\MakeLowercase{https://intothecryptoverse.com/}}

% [LianTze] times (the package not the font) is rather outdated now; use newtx (see later)
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{picinpar}
%uasage of picinpar:
%\begin{window}[1,l,\includegraphics{},caption]xxxxx\end{window}

%% [LianTze] Contains some modifications
%\usepackage{newspaper-mod}
%%... so now you can redefine the headline and byline style if you want to.
%% These can be issued just before any
%% byline or headline in the paper, to
%% individually style each article
%%
% \renewcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\Large\lsstyle}
% \renewcommand{\bylinestyle}{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}


%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{-40pt}
\begin{center}
{\setlength\fboxsep{3mm}\raisebox{12pt}{\framebox[1.2\width]{\parbox[c]{1.15in}{\begin{center}\small \@paperslogan\end{center}}}}}\hfill%
{\Huge\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n} \@papername}\hfill%    % <==================
\raisebox{12pt}{\textbf{\footnotesize \@paperlocation}}\\
\vspace*{0.1in}
\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\
{\small VOL.\MakeUppercase{\roman{volume}}\ldots No.\arabic{issue}} \hfill \MakeUppercase{\small\it\@date} \hfill {\small\MakeUppercase{\@paperprice}}\\
\rule[6pt]{\textwidth}{1.2pt}
\end{center}
\pagestyle{plain}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}

\byline{Introduction }{Benjamin J. Cowen}

\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\closearticle
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Personal remark: I like the version with fractur font, not this one ...